# enable button if all 2 dimensions radio button checked/ picked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make some form to score each option a value which is cannot be the same value, I've done it by 2 Dimensional radio button, the next problem is, the user must not proceed to next column if not ranked all the option, I can do the next column if it only 1 radio button checked by `javascript` document on change, so I have the idea to do this.

```
$(document).on('change', '.answer1', function(){
$(document).on('change', '.answer2', function(){
$(document).on('change', '.answer3', function(){
$(document).on('change', '.answer4', function(){
$(this).closest('.cont').find('.next').removeAttr("disabled");
```

sometimes its work, but sometimes its don't, can

```js
$('.cont').addClass('hide');
count = $('.questions').length;
$('#question' + 1).removeClass('hide');

$(document).on('click', '.next', function() {
  last = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  nex = last + 1;
  $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');
  $('#question' + nex).removeClass('hide');
  console.log(nex);
});

$(document).on('click', '.previous', function() {
  last = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  pre = last - 1;
  $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');

  $('#question' + pre).removeClass('hide');
});
$(document).on('change', '.answer1', function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.answer2', function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.answer3', function() {
      $(document).on('change', '.answer4', function() {
        $(this).closest('.cont').find('.next').removeAttr("disabled");
      })
    })
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var col, el;

      $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        el = $(this);
        col = el.data("col");
        $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
        el.prop("checked", true);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="quiz6.php">
    <div id='question1' class='cont'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>option 1</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="11>" data-col="11" value="1" class="answer1>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="11>" data-col="12" value="2" class="answer2>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="11>" data-col="13" value="3" class="answer3>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="11>" data-col="14" value="4" class="answer4>" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>option 2</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="12>" data-col="11" value="1" class="answer1>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="12>" data-col="12" value="2" class="answer2>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="12>" data-col="13" value="3" class="answer3>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="12>" data-col="14" value="4" class="answer4>" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>option 3</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="13>" data-col="11" value="1" class="answer1>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="13>" data-col="12" value="2" class="answer2>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="13>" data-col="13" value="3" class="answer3>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="13>" data-col="14" value="4" class="answer4>" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>option 4</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="14>" data-col="11" value="1" class="answer1>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="14>" data-col="12" value="2" class="answer2>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="14>" data-col="13" value="3" class="answer3>" required></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="14>" data-col="14" value="4" class="answer4>" required></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id='1' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' disabled>Next</button>
</body>

</html>
```

to be honest I don't know why it works/ didn't works. I don't know if it possible to do by my way, is it any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add condition to check total checked radio buttons like below.

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    el = $(this);
    col = el.data("col");
    $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
    el.prop("checked", true);
    if($("input[data-col]:checked").length == 4){
        $("button").prop('disabled',false);
    }else{
        $("button").prop('disabled',true);
    }
  });
```

I hope it will help you. (I used button directly which might conflict with outher button on page).

Comment: can you approve my edit for more than 1 column use? thanks for your anser, its worked :)